# Is there a way to add a CSRF token validation on GET requests in Django to mitigate GET requests to a JSON API?

Tags: django, angularjs, security

I'm currently building a webapp using Angular JS and Django. At [this point](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#json-vulnerability-protection) in the angular documentation, I was led to [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/) about the vulnerabilities of JSON GET requests. Django supports a CSRF protection mechanism, but as far as I can tell there is no way to enforce it on GET requests. I think I would prefer this mechanism to what Angular suggests (prepending every JSON response with `)]}',` ), but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create your own middleware class to check for CSRF token's in GET requests or mannually check for a CSRF header inside your views. Either way your ajax request needs to set the `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` header with the CSRF token